# ¿Como puedo obtener un map de un documento con cloud firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Con la siguiente base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando quiero obtener los datos de un usuario lo hago con:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("usuarios").document("Jose");
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        City city = documentSnapshot.toObject(Usuario.class);
    }
});
```

Donde la clase usuario seria algo como:

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable {
private String nombre;
private Map<String, Object> telefonos;

public Usuario(){}

public Usuario(String nombre, Map<String, Object> telefonos) {
    this.nombre= nombre;
    this.telefonos= telefonos;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public Map<String, Object> getTelefonos() {
    return telefonos;
}
```

En el map hay valores de tipo number y otros de tipo String, de ahi el Map<String, Object>

Al crear el usuario, el valor del map "Telefonos" siempre es null.
¿Como puedo obtener el map del cloud firestore?

Comment: La clase `Usuario` debe tener un *setter* para todos los miembros, de lo contrario el mapeo no se hará correctamente. Si observas la consola verás que te pone mensajes del tipo *No setter found for ...*  o algo parecido. Para mapear `Telefonos` deberías tener algo así: `public void setTelefonos(HashMap<String, Object> telefonos) { this.telefonos = telefonos; }`, y declara el miembro del tipo `HashMap`, algo así: `private HashMap<String, Object> telefonos;`  y, por convención de nombre, en Firestore deberías llamar a la clave `telefonos` con `t` minúscula. No sé si el mapeo es case sensitive.

Comment: Gracias, con lo que me has dicho ya funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es el codigo funcionando, gracias a A. Cedano.
Hay que cambiar la clase Usuario, **añadiendo un get y un set** y cambiando el **Map por HashMap**

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable {
    private String nombre;
    private HashMap<String, Object> telefonos;

    public Usuario(){}

    public Usuario(String nombre, HashMap<String, Object> telefonos) {
        this.nombre= nombre;
        this.telefonos= telefonos;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Object> getTelefonos() {
        return telefonos;
    }

    public void setTelefonos(HashMap<String, Object> telefonos) { 
        this.telefonos = telefonos; 
    }
}
```